# How to turn ON location services through Code

Tags: iphone

**How to turn ON location services through Code** in my application if location service is in OFF condition i want it to ON  through alertView i have two buttons in alertview cancel & settings 
if i click settings it needs to go settings of the device is it possible???

Could anyone help me??

thanks...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to deal with the same problem but this is just not possible under iOS. You have to check if location services is enabled :

```
[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
```

and if not, ask the user to go to the settings to enable it (through an AlertView for example).

Note that Apple says :

> locationServicesEnabled : You should check the return value of this
>   method before starting location updates to determine if the user has
>   location services enabled for the current device. If this method
>   returns NO and you start location updates anyway, the Core Location
>   framework prompts the user with a confirmation panel asking whether
>   location services should be reenabled.

But that only seem to work the very first time you check. If the user denies, the confirmation panel is not shown anymore.

You may also check :

```
switch ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]) {

        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
    }
```

Comment: @Deepak : don't lose time, you can't. If you really want to do it, you may search for undocumented methods, but your app will be rejected by Apple.

Comment: i used the above **if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]==NO)**                                        {                                                                    // alertview                                                             }

Answer (score 4):

You can't enable location services in code. You just invoke the service, and iOS will seek permission from the user on behalf of your app.